# Visibility of template function specialisations in shared libraries; dependence on template parameter

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, template-specialization, undefined-symbol

I am building some C++ code that utilises [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) to do some wrapping and create a Python extension module, and I am encountering some undefined symbol problems. Upon further examination, it appears to be because certain template function specialisations are not publically visible in the shared library I am building.

I have a MWE to demonstrate explicitly the problem:

symbol_test.hpp

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

template <typename T>
void test_func(T var) {}

template <>
void test_func<int>(int);

template <>
void test_func<pybind11::object>(pybind11::object);
```

symbol_test.cpp

```
#include "symbol_test.hpp"

template <>
void test_func<int>(int var) {}

template <>
void test_func<pybind11::object>(pybind11::object var) {}
```

Build command:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -fPIC -I/home/farmer/anaconda3/envs/default/include/python2.7 -I/home/farmer/repos/pybind11/include -shared -o testlib.so symbol_test.cpp
```

Inspect library with nm:

```
nm testlib.so
...
00000000000024d0 T _Z9test_funcIiEvT_
00000000000024da t _Z9test_funcIN8pybind116objectEEvT_
...
```

In short, the instance of test_func specialised on "int" is visible, but the instance specialised on "pybind11::object" is not. Why? How do I control this? I need the pybind11::object version of the function to be exported in the library, but I don't know why it isn't.

I ask the question here rather than submit it as a pybind11 bug because I just assume there is something I don't understand about how template functions symbols are exported in shared libraries, rather than it being a deficiency in pybind11.

Edit: I had a thought; pybind11 is a header-only library, so I suppose the code for the pybind11::object class is not getting built or something? And this is affecting the visibility of template functions which use it?

Comment: As per your question, after inspecting shared library using nm command you are getting `00000000000024d0 T _Z9test_funcIiEvT_   
00000000000024da t _Z9test_funcIN8pybind116objectEEvT_`  but it is not undefined symbol, See this: [ http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/nm.htm]

Comment: T symbol stand for : The symbol is in the text (code) section.

Comment: Yes I know, but from the nm manual: "If lowercase, the symbol is usually local; if uppercase, the symbol is global (external)." So symbols with lowercase t will not be found by the linker when I try to actually use this library elsewhere. At that point the linker will complain about undefined references.

Comment: why you are giving one function definition in header file and other definition in cpp file.

Comment: Only the general template function is defined in the header. The specialisations are defined in the cpp file. The general template cannot go in the cpp file. Or at least that is not a useful place to put it.

Comment: if I define all the function in cpp file, I am getting this after inspecting share library using nm command : `0000000000002800 T _Z9test_funcIiEvT_   
000000000000280a T _Z9test_funcIN8pybind116objectEEvT` ,

Comment: both the function with uppercase T

Comment: Hmm I don't. Perhaps it is compiler dependent. What are you using? I am using gcc 5.4.0.

Comment: I am using gcc 5.3.1

Comment: `template <typename T>
void test_func(T var) { return var; }` in this function the return type is void and you are returning var with return type T. Why is it so ?

Comment: Oh whoops, no reason. Just left over from a previous test. I'm pretty sure it is irrelevant to the problem though.

Comment: Please change void type to T and remove compilation error. Giving few compilation errors

Comment: Nah just delete the function body. I have updated the question.

Comment: Ben it is working fine for me and I am not getting any undefined symbol error also.... can you provide your program with gcc command line for which you are using testlib.so and getting error.

Comment: I can come up with something tomorrow, but if you are getting the "T", as you said earlier, then indeed you should not get any linking errors using the library function. So that doesn't tell us too much, except that this is apparently compiler dependent. I'll try with a different compiler tomorrow as well.

Comment: Yes I am getting "T" as symbol type for both functions, yup that may be the reason I am not getting any linking error.

Comment: Pass `--demangle/-C` to `nm` to make it demangle C++ symbols.

Comment: Ok I just tried it with gcc 7.3.0 and get the same result. Perhaps it is pybind that has changed, my project may not be up to date with their latest release. I'll try that, though I'd still like to know what it is that causes this behaviour.

Comment: Nope, same result with latest pybind11 in their git repo.